# Snowflake vs Azure SQL for Archival storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a table in Azure SQL instance db. Around 15 M records gets populated in that table every month. We are thinking to have archival process to archive the data after every 60 days.

For now, we are thinking archived data will just be used for debugging purpose. This might need some indexing because it may contain lot of data. However, this is for future, we may want to keep that in our overall decision.

We have 2 options for destination db store. Snowflake or Azure SQL.
I have looked at the cost to store the data in snowflake or azure sql. Seems it depends on different factors. And I feel it might end up with same cost.

We are also thinking to leverage ADF to move data (move from Azure SQL to Snowflake if we go with snowflake as destination db for archival).
Or just use Azure Functions which will run daily to move data from one table to other archival table in azure sql.

We are thinking to purge/delete the data from data archive store after 2 years.

Frequency of Data archival store usage will be very minimal as it contains data older than 60 days. But, let's expect it once in a month.

Any suggestions for data store in terms of cost and future usage and overall work would be highly appreciated?

Comment: people often use columnstore indexes to store historical data.   In fact, the temporal tables feature in SQL uses that by default in temporal history tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches which you can try.

You can create a `Stored Procedure` within your database to delete the data which is older than 2 years. Trigger the stored procedure via Azure Data Factory using (ADF) [`Stored Procedure Activity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) on a monthly or adhoc scheduled basis.

To store the 60 days old data in archive, you can create a BACPAC file of your database and store it in Azure Blob Storage. You can use **access tier** feature of Blob Storage which allows you to store data in Hot/Cool/Archive access tier.

You can use archive access tier if you just need to access it once in a month.

In case, if required to restore the data quickly, you can update the Blob container from cool/archive to hot and use ADF to copy data from BACPAC file to  database.

Comment: I guess BACPAC file is something we need to import every time when we want to query historical data. We may need some storage instead where we can query the data whenever we want instead of importing files. Thanks!

Comment: For  BACPAC, Azure Blob Storage is the best option. You can create a archive container which will cost less. But for query you must import the file to database, no other option is there.

Comment: can we programmatically using c# or azure functions export or import file to blob container?

Comment: and instead of one database, can we export just one table to bacpac file? Also, if we create one bacpac file per month resulting in to multiple bacpac files in a year, can we import multiple bacpac files as needed in one table later? If yes, how do we do that?